# Verify that $abc^2x^2+c(3a^2+b^2)x+3a^2-ab+b^2=0$ has real roots

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math, quadratics

As the title states, the goal is to verify that the quadratic equation: $abc^2x^2+c(3a^2+b^2)x+3a^2-ab+b^2=0$ has real roots. This problem comes from an interschool mathematics contest for High-schoolers, here's my (brute force) attempt:

Since we need to verify that the roots are rational, we need to prove that the discriminant of this equation (which I'll denote with $D$) is greater than $0$. In other words:

$D=B^2-4AC>0$ where $B=c(3a^2+b^2)$, $A=abc^2$ and $C=3a^2-ab+b^2$ Therefore:

$D=[c(3a^2+b^2)]^2-4(abc^2)(3a^2-ab+b^2)$

$D=[c^2(9a^4+6a^2b^2+b^4)]+[c^2(-12a^3b+4a^2b^2-4ab^3)]$

$D=c^2(9a^4+10a^2b^2+b^4-12a^3b-4ab^3)$

I'm not quite sure where to proceed from here. And this certainly does not prove that the roots are real as this expression can be negative. Is there a way to proceed from here? Are there any better or alternative ways to answer this? Please share your approaches!

Comment: Hint : $D$ is a perfect square. Start dividing by $c^2$

Comment: How did you deduce that $D$ is a perfect square? @ClaudeLeibovici

Comment: $D = {c}^{2} \left( 3\,{a}^{2}-2\,ab+{b}^{2} \right) ^{2}$.  If it is a square of something with integer coefficients, it is not too hard to find.  Because of this, it suggests the original polynomial can be factored using (at least rational) coefficients.  Indeed, $$ab{c}^{2}{x}^{2}+c \left( 3\,{a}^{2}+{b}^{2} \right) x+3\,{a}^{2}-ab+{
b}^{2}= \left( cx+1 \right)  \left( abcx+3\,{a}^{2}-ab+{b}^{2}
 \right)$$

Comment: @GEdgar Would you mind posting an answer about how you arrived at that expression? That might be the best way to solve the problem and likely what was intended by those who created the question

Comment: Another option would be with the obvious substitution $cx=y$, note that $ab\,y^2+(3a^2+b^2)\,y+3a^2-ab+b^2=0$ has the root $y=-1$.

Comment: Question is originally from the classic 'Higher Algebra' by H S Hall and S R Knight

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$
p(x) = ab{c}^{2}{x}^{2}+c \left( 3\,{a}^{2}+{b}^{2} \right) x+3\,{a}^{2}-ab+{b}^{2} .
$$
Let's try to factor this with the idea of finding a factor $Ax+B$ where $A$ is a divisor of $abc^2$ and $B$ is a divisor of $3a^2-ab+b^2$.  Since $3a^2-ab+b^2$ cannot be factored over the rationals, we try without factoring it.  (If this doesn't work, we have to do something harder.)  The possible factors of $p(x)$ are $Ax+B$ where
$$
A \in \big\{1, a, b, ab, c, ac, bc, abc, c^2, ac^2, bc^2, abc^2\big\} ,
\\
B \in \big\{1, -1, (3a^2-ab+b^2), -(3a^2-ab+b^2)\big\} .
$$
Trying these four candidates for $B$ until one works, we arrive at:
$$
p(x)= \left( cx+1 \right)  \left( abcx+(3\,{a}^{2}-ab+{b}^{2})\right)
$$

Comment: Thank you for this. I didn't think factoring was possible. Furthermore, can you please elaborate how you got $D=c^2(3a^2-2ab+b^2)^2$?

Answer (score 3):

It seems your approach is the most straightforward, and you are almost done. Observe that WLOG we may assume $a, b \ge0$, and we, by AM-GM, have:

$$9a^4+10a^2b^2+b^4 \ge (6a^4+6a^2b^2)+(4a^2b^2+b^4) \ge  12a^3b +4ab^3.$$

---

**EDIT:** Another easy way is: $D=c^2(3a^4+6(a^2-ab)^2+(b^2-2ab)^2),$ not using the AM-GM inequality.

Comment: Thank you, that's definitely a good way to proceed using the AM-GM inequality. I'm not sure jf high schoolers would know this, but this is a good approach nonetheless

Comment: @Goku Ok, in this sense, notice that $D=c^2(3a^4+6(a^2-ab)^2+(b^2-2ab)^2)$.

Answer (score 1):

Since this problem was written for high-school contestants, I also have my doubts as to how many of them would spot the factorability of the discriminant.  I decided to take the approach of writing the quadratic polynomial in "vertex form", thus
$$ abc^2·x^2 \ + \ c·( \ 3a^2 + b^2 \ )·x \ + \ ( \ 3a^2 - ab + b^2 \ ) $$
$$ = \ \ abc^2 · \left[ \ x^2 \ + \ \frac{\overbrace{3a^2 \ + \ b^2}^{K}}{abc}·x \ \right] \ + \ ( \ K \ - \ ab \ ) $$
$$ = \ \ abc^2 · \left( \ x  \ + \ \frac{K}{2abc} \ \right)^2 \ + \ \left( \ K \ - \ ab \ - \ \frac{K^2}{4a^2b^2c^2}·abc^2 \ \right) $$
$$ = \ \ abc^2 · \left( \ x  \ + \ \frac{K}{2abc} \ \right)^2 \ + \ \left( \ K \ - \ ab \ - \ \frac{K^2}{4ab} \ \right)  \ \ , $$
with $ \ K \ > \ 0 \ $ and (necessarily) $ \ ab \ \neq \ 0 \ \ . \ $  (I am presuming, as it is not stated, that $ \ a \ , \ b \ , \ c \ $ are all real.)

The only sign dependence of significance in this expression is that of the recurrent factor $ \ ab \ \ : \  $  if $ \ ab \ > \ 0 \ \  $ (the parabola "opens upward"), then this quadratic polynomial has real zeroes if $ \ \left( \ K \ - \ ab \ - \ \frac{K^2}{4ab} \ \right) \ \le \ 0 \ \ ; \ $ if $ \ ab \ < \ 0 \ \  $ (the parabola "opens downward"), then the direction of this "coefficients" inequality is reversed.  With $ \ ab \ > \ 0 \ , \ $ the term $ \  \frac{K^2}{4ab} \ $ is also positive, so it remains to determine whether $ \ K \ \le \ ab \ + \ \frac{K^2}{4ab} \ \ . \ $   Since both the numerator and denominator in these ratios are positive, we may apply the AM-GM inequality to show that indeed
$$  \frac{ ab  \ + \ \frac{K^2}{4ab}}{2} \ \ \ge \ \ \sqrt{ab · \frac{K^2}{4ab} } \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ ab  \ + \ \frac{K^2}{4ab} \ \ \ge \ \ 2·\sqrt{ \frac{K^2}{4} } \ = \ K \ \ . $$
Hence, $ \ \left( \ K \ - \ ab \ - \ \frac{K^2}{4ab} \ \right) \ \le \ 0 \ $ for this case.  [This portion ends up being similar to **Reza Rajaei**'s argument.]  With $ \ ab \ < \ 0 \ \ , \ \ K \ - \ ab \ - \ \frac{K^2}{4ab} \ $ is equivalent to a *sum* of three *positive* terms, hence $ \ \left( \ K \ - \ ab \ - \ \frac{K^2}{4ab} \ \right) \ \ge \ 0 \ \ . $

Therefore, the polynomial in question always has at least one real zero.  (Other than that we must have $ \ c \ \neq \ 0 \ \ , \ $ the value of $ \ c \ $ is of no consequence for this conclusion.)